# Problema de conexão com banco .mdf

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-localdb

Estou com um empecilho na hora de conectar minha aplicação *C#* (*Windows Forms*) com um banco de dados em `.MDF`, que já esta inserido na pasta do projeto.

No computador do curso funcionou normalmente, porém em casa já coloquei o nome da instância do SQL Server mas não consigo me conectar ao banco, retorna a seguinte mensagem[image: Erro do SQL]

Estou usando o SQL Server Developer 2012. O nome da instância é o nome que esta no *wizard* de configuração do SQL Server.

Comment: Você instalou o sql server ou express na sua maquina?

Comment: Gilvane poderia incluir mais detalhes? Como a query de conexão utilizada, etc.

Comment: Pode por favor editar sua pergunta e inserir os dados da seção `<connectionStrings>` do seu `Web.config`?

Comment: Certeza que é um problema na connectionString do web.config.